# In which comics does the Silver Surfer appear as the Silver Savage?

Tags: marvel, silver-surfer

My son recently saw some images of the Silver Surfer as the Silver Savage and thinks he is the coolest super hero ever.  I wanted to see if I could get him one of the comics where the Silver Savage appears.

I am pretty sure he is the Silver Savage when he is forced to fight the Hulk but I can't seem to find the definitive list of comics.

My son is only 3.5 years old but he likes to look at the pictures, so bonus points for indicating any which might be reasonably suitable for a preschooler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### You are looking for the "Planet Hulk: Exile" saga in The Incredible Hulk Vol 2, #95. The Silver Savage makes his first appearance in this series.

[image]

- The Silver Savage is the Silver Surfer who crashes on during the Planet Hulk storyline and finds himself weakened, captured and turned into an unwilling gladiator using an alien technology.
- I am sorry this particular battle is both fierce and unrelenting. I doubt you will find many images in that particular comic where the Silver Savage is appropriate for young children. You may find some fan art which might prove a bit more appropriate such as the piece below done by [Statman on DeviantART](http://statman71.deviantart.com/art/Planet-Hulk-vs-Silver-Savage-161998462).

[image]

Comment: I always thought the Silver Surfer seemed out of place in the story. In the film, they used Beta-Ray Bill instead, which made a lot more sense to me.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Oh well I guess we will have to content ourselves with drawing our own for a while.

Comment: Beta Ray Bill WAS a much better fit.

Comment: I never heard of the Silver Savage, so I might sound stupid, but are we sure it's the same individual? I mean, isn't this someone else of the same species?

Comment: Silver Surfer isn't a species - he's a unique individual created when Galactus converted Norin Radd (who appeared human) into his herald. This WAS, in fact, THE Silver Surfer, albeit he was being manipulated.